# Xcode is very laggy with lots of View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

My project contains over 60 View Controllers and Xcode is very laggy when loading the storyboard.

How can I resolve this without switching to xibs? I am using Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.x

Comment: What is lagging: the Xcode storyboard editor, or the execution of the app?

Comment: When you mean "views", you mean "ViewControllers", right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

Putting all of your **ViewControllers** in one **Storyboard** will significantly slow down **Xcode** (which renders **XML** to show your **ViewControllers**) if the number of the **ViewControllers** is above 10. **Storyboard** is not the place to put all of your views, because as its name suggests a board of a specific story.

### Solution

Make multiple **Storyboards** with 5 or 6 **ViewControllers** each, where you can avoid rendering hell of multiple **ViewControllers**. You can divide your Application on different boards named by group functionality like LoginStoryboard, UserProfileStoryboard, etc.

You can instantiate a storyboard and present a specific controller by the code below:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your Storyboard Name" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your Controller ID"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep views in more than one storyboard. It's not the problem if not every controllers are connected with segues. There is no good way to keep a large number of views in a storyboard, in addition to working on a better computer.